# What is the proper way to fire two scripts: one that loads data and another that manipulates styling?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, dom-events

I'm running a website that dynamically loads a new headline at refresh using JavaScript. I should mention, my site is extremely tiny so I'm purposefully avoiding using jQuery or any other JS libraries.

First script loads a JSON file and randomly selects an entry into the HTML. Second script "attempts" to check if the document's length runs past the viewport, if it does, shrink the text and check again.

```
ajax.request("GET","file.json"); // works fine
preventScroll.resize(".headline"); // not so much
```

However, I can't get the second script to work reliably. I've tried loading both through `window.onload`, I've tried moving it from the HEAD tag to immediately before the end of the BODY tag.

[Scripts in question](https://gist.github.com/reneruiz/0fba9f66049c5c8e51b4)

[Live Example](http://dev.thingscicadasmissed.com/)

How should I properly call these so they always work?

Comment: Since it's such a simple website, could you create a jsFiddle example?

Comment: Isn't ajax.request() a prototype call and not straight JS?

Comment: So the question is really just about the second script?

Comment: elclanrs, [try this](http://dev.thingscicadasmissed.com/)

Jack, I suppose, the second one relies on the first one. So I assumed I may have to make changes to the first one, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not exposing a success handler in your `ajax` "library". I would suggest making these changes:

```
var makeRequest = function(method, url, success) {
```

Then inside the function:

```
//...
if (httpRequest.status === ajaxState.isOkay) {
    data = httpRequest.responseText;
    successHandler(data);
    success(); // you could call with more arguments
}
```

To use the whole thing together:

```
ajax.request("GET","file.json", function() {
    preventScroll.resize(".headline");
});
```

Comment: It never occurred to me to use them together like that. I love this! Thanks Jack. :)